# Typescript Idle Timer with UseRef

Tags: reactjs, typescript, idle-timer

On the verge of giving up on Typescript, everything just seems to be made harder. Trying to follow a simple react-idle-timer video and a few minutes in already facing Typescript compilation problems. Searching online for guides on how to use useRef with typescript says to just put the type you expect in <> when making the useRef call. On paper that sounds good to me and should work, yet here I am facing issues yet again with TS.

```
import { useRef } from 'react';
import IdleTimer from 'react-idle-timer';

function IdleTimerContainer() {
    const idleTimerRef = useRef<IdleTimer | null>(null);
    function onIdle() {
        console.log('user is idle');
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <IdleTimer timeout={5 * 1000} onIdle={onIdle} ref={idleTimerRef} />
        </div>
    );
}
export default IdleTimerContainer;
```

> TS2769: No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 2, '(props: IdleTimerClassProps | Readonly): IdleTimer', gave the following error.     Type 'MutableRefObject<IdleTimer | null>' is not assignable to type '(LegacyRef & ((ref: IdleTimer) => any)) | undefined'.       Type 'MutableRefObject<IdleTimer | null>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject & ((ref: IdleTimer) => any)'.         Type 'MutableRefObject<IdleTimer | null>' is not assignable to type '(ref: IdleTimer) => any'.           Type 'MutableRefObject<IdleTimer | null>' provides no match for the signature '(ref: IdleTimer): any'.   Overload 2 of 2, '(props: IdleTimerClassProps, context: any): IdleTimer', gave the following error.     Type 'MutableRefObject<IdleTimer | null>' is not assignable to type '(LegacyRef & ((ref: IdleTimer) => any)) | undefined'.  index.d.ts(143, 9): The expected type comes from property 'ref' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly & Readonly<...>' index.d.ts(143, 9): The expected type comes from property 'ref' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly & Readonly<...>'

Comment: try `useRef<IdleTimer>(null);`

Comment: That was the first thing I tried :'D. @Kay

Comment: yep and then you are suppose to do the checks - see, https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react/hooks/#useref `if (idleTimerRef  && idleTimerRef.current){...}`

Comment: Adding   `if (idleTimerRef && idleTimerRef.current) {
        console.log('typecheck');
    }` still isn't working

Answer (score 4):

It's not your fault!  Your code is fine, it's the `react-idle-timer` package itself that's doing it wrong.

```
interface IdleTimerClassProps extends IdleTimerProps {
    /**
     * React reference to the IdleTimer Component instance.
     */
    ref?: (ref: IdleTimer) => any
}
```

This section of the [source code](https://github.com/SupremeTechnopriest/react-idle-timer/blob/114f4640e951622184af0307843c58afbed4cb73/src/index.d.ts#L193) makes it so that you can only use a callback style ref and not a ref object.

Your ref object should be just a TS issue, not a JS issue, so you can circumvent the problems with the package by using `as any`.

```
<IdleTimer timeout={5 * 1000} onIdle={onIdle} ref={idleTimerRef as any} />
```

You'll still have proper TypeScript types on the `idleTimerRef` variable.